# Android OutOfMemoryError when Fragment's onCreateView called

Tags: android, android-fragments, out-of-memory

I have an Activity with fragment inside. On some devices like Xiaomi application crashes and `OutOfMemoryError` thrown. There's stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9437196 byte allocation with 5089232 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
   at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2937)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2669)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2569)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
   at com.rcd.perfecto.ui.fragments.AuthFragment.onCreateView(AuthFragment.java:154)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1988)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1250)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:2148)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentController.java:247)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:804)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:790)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:367)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6474)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1143)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3823)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5432)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:735)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
```

The exception is thrown when called `onCreateView` method of `AuthFragment`. There's method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    return view;
}
```

Exception is thrown on line `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);` What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you loading any large image in your `ImageView` in xml layout?

Comment: I have an ImageView in layout and I pass there one image with size about 70 KB and it's static

Comment: Try to load that dynamically in java using image loading libraries like Glide, picasso.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: You are trying to allocate about 9MB of memory. android:largeHeap may save you, but...if your image is 70kb it is really strange that you are trying to allocate 9MB. You can also try to change your drawable folder name from "drawable" to "drawable-nodpi". If your folder is "drawable", it is interpreted from runtime as "drawable-mdpi" which is not exactly what you want :)

Comment: Improving your apps memory usage should be first port of call. Ensuring excess objects aren't being allocated, recycling Bitmaps, discarding resources when no longer required etc. Too many developers lazily enable large heap just so they don't have to learn how to code efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

You can use largeHeap in your Application. Just add to Manifest:

```
    <application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...
```